# Gems missing error when running rspec programatically but working fine directly with rspec command

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

When i run rspec programatically (RSpec::Core::Runner.run(['spec/apis/my_spec.rb']) )i am getting gems missing error.

```
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'em-synchrony' (>= 1.0.0) among 175 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0:/usr/local/bundle', execute `gem env` for more information
```

But its working fine when i run the specs using rspec command.

rspec --pattern spec/apis/my_spec.rb --format nested

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you require the gem in the code that executes the test?